# Help Identifying "Up Left Arrow" Android / Material Design Icon & Usage

Tags: android, icons, material-design

Could someone please tell me the name of this "up left arrow" icon used in Google / Chrome mobile search bar list? (Icon highlighted in image) I looked around but couldn't find any info.

Also, does it have a specific meaning and usage?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Searching on the internet "diagonal arrow search results" yields results such as [Quick Tip: Long Press Google Search Suggestions To Pop Them Into The Search Bar](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/02/13/quick-tip-long-press-google-search-suggestions-to-pop-them-into-the-search-bar/). From the site:

> Remember that little diagonal arrow that used to appear next to suggestions in the Google Search box as you typed? The arrows could be used to insert suggestions into the search bar, while you kept typing away.

Comment: Ha, thanks - I was Googling for the icon itself. I guess there is no name for it? Material Design doesn't have it listed.

The arrow still shows up for me as default on the Google search app, as well as Chrome, Google Earth app, and Youtube app. So I wonder if they went back to it.

But are they are now trying to phase it out?

There are no arrow icons in search list for Play Store app, and Ebay app

thank you

Answer (score 2):

As above the icon is used add the suggestion into your current search so that you can carry on typing, clicking the word would just search for the suggestion.

Google are still using the icon in Oreo and the latest Pixel launcher/feed so I can't see them phasing it out. The icon isn't in the Material icon pack but is the same as the call made and call received icons, they just need to be rotated to point in the correct direction.

https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=call_made

Answer (score 1):

This is the Android Vector Drawable top-left arrow. I mirrored [ic_call_made](https://material.io/icons/#ic_call_made) from material icons, as suggested by @Stephen C.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M15 5L15 7L8.41 7L20 18.59L18.59 20L7 8.41L7 15L5 15L5 5Z"/>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 1):

We call this icon "fling" icon...

Comment: Hey Rohit, where have you seen this name and who are "we"? Adding sometimes sources here creates more successful and meaningful answers.